# Forwarding a request with custom routes in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am working with custom routes in zend framework. I had managed my custom routes successfully
but I had a problem i.e. I want to forward a request according some predefined condition after routing but I am unable to forward my. I did not get any error.

Following is the code of routing configuration file -

;---        routing for multiple requests

```
routes.resource.route = "resource/:moduleName/:fileType/"
routes.resource.defaults.controller = resources
routes.resource.defaults.module = 'default'
routes.resource.defaults.action = 'index'
```

;---        routing for singles file

```
routes.resourceCSS.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.resourceCSS.route = "resource/(\w+)/([a-zA-z0-9]+\.([a-zA-z0-9]+))"
routes.resourceCSS.defaults.module = 'default'
routes.resourceCSS.defaults.controller = "resources"
routes.resourceCSS.defaults.action = checkfiletype
routes.resourceCSS.map.moduleName = 1
routes.resourceCSS.map.fileName = 2
routes.resourceCSS.map.fileType =  3
```

controller name is **resources**
Follwoing is code of controller : -

```
class ResourcesController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{


   public function checkfiletypeAction()
   {
       var_dump($this->_getAllParams());
       $moduleName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('moduleName');
       $fileName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('fileName');
       $fileType = strtolower($this->getRequest()->getParam('fileType'));

       switch($fileType)
       {
        case 'css' :
            echo $fileType ;
            $this->_forward('css') ;
            break ;
        case 'js' :
            $this->_forward('js') ;
            break ;
        default :
            break;

       }

       die();
   }


   public function cssAction()
   {
      var_dump($this->_getAllParams());
      die();

   }

   public function jsAction()
   {
      var_dump($this->_getAllParams());
      die();
   }
```

}

Please help me.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, have you tried without that die(); at the end of your checkfiletypeAction function?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but was not succeessful

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in numbers as your filetype, and checking for words:

```
;ini file
routes.resourceCSS.map.fileType =  3


//controller    
case 'css' :
```

Change the case to match the number:

```
//controller
case '3' :
```

Comment: this is not an issue. I face problem only when I tried to forward a request to resources action. If if forward request to another controller, it works fine but my requirement is to move request on same controller

Comment: Sorry, I misread the original code. You are using a Regex route and you are passing in the third parenthesis as this parameter. Could you do a var_dump of fileType? Confirm exactly what is being supplied?